# Background color broken in NavigationView in iOS 16 - SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ios16

Prior to iOS 16, screen background in a `NavigationView` used to work very reliably in SwiftUI.

In iOS 16, there is a hollow space (without background color) when navigating back and forth with on-screen-keyboard:

[image: demo]

Repro code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Edit field", text: $text)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Naviagtion target")) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "link")
                        Text("Navigation Link")
                    }
                }
                .padding(30)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.gray)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It does look and feel like a bug, where the safe area that’s adjusted when the keyboard appears doesn’t re-adjust when you navigate back and the keyboard’s not there.

One way round the bug is to adjust the background’s idea of what the safe area is, by telling it to always reclaim the keyboard space:

```swift
.background(
  Color.gray
    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
)
```

Because you’re only adjusting the safe area for the background, the rest of your view should continue to behave as before. That means that it’s still elevated to accommodate the (missing) keyboard’s space requirement, but it’s less obvious.

Comment: Great idea! I only suggest a small change: instead of `.ignoreSafeArea(.keyboard)` I had to use `.ignoreSafeArea(.all)` otherwise I get black bars above and below my view. Apart from that perfect, I'd accept as an answer. You are right that the content is still elevated, which really looks like an iOS bug, still present in 16.1 :(